# Dart read json objects from Uneditable large file

Tags: dart

i have a large file which that uneditable and i have more `jsonObject` into that, for example:

```
{"id":"@123456","v":"1"}
```

this isn't `jsonArray` which i can't parse and read it, for example:

```
String file= new File('file.json').readAsStringSync();
Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(file);
```

you think how can i read this objects from file and show key and values?

Comment: When you say the file is large is that because it is too large to have all the content in memory at the same time so you want a streaming solution? Or is it small enough that you can parse all objects in one go and then put the data into a list?

Comment: @julemand101 its enough to put only all `id` in objects to another file

Comment: Ok, so you just want to get the `id` of each object and put it into another file? Is the objects represented as stated in the question? So the json are saved as multiple lines. Because if that is the case, you could easily just run through the file and grep each line containing the `id` field and parse it.

Comment: @julemand101 yes, i want to get only `id` and store it into another file, i don't know how can i get each objects from file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution. I ended up making a parser for your input format which are returning each parsed JSON object in a Stream.

The parser will not work if any strings in your JSON contains `{` or `}`. If that is the case, I can expand the parser so it takes this into account but I don't want to make it more advanced than necessary.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  final ids = await File('large_file.json')
      .openRead()
      .transform(const Utf8Decoder())
      .transform<dynamic>(JsonObjectTransformer())
      .map((dynamic json) => json['id'] as String)
      .toList();

  print(ids); // [@123456, @123456]
}

class JsonObjectTransformer extends StreamTransformerBase<String, dynamic> {
  static final _openingBracketChar = '{'.codeUnitAt(0);
  static final _closingBracketChar = '}'.codeUnitAt(0);

  @override
  Stream<dynamic> bind(Stream<String> stream) async* {
    final sb = StringBuffer();
    var bracketsCount = 0;

    await for (final string in stream) {
      for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        final current = string.codeUnitAt(i);
        sb.writeCharCode(current);

        if (current == _openingBracketChar) {
          bracketsCount++;
        }

        if (current == _closingBracketChar && --bracketsCount == 0) {
          yield json.decode(sb.toString());
          sb.clear();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i think this code only work on formatted json, for example your code can't find `id` from this structure `{"id":"@123456","@version":"1","typ":"cfm","access_hash":"788468819702098896","user_id":1,"@timestamp":"2020-01-26T13:53:29.467Z","path":"/home/user/","type":"text","flags":2135,"host":"ubuntu","imported_from":"account"}`

Comment: Yes, as stated in my answer "This solution is based on the file format is the same as provided so each key-value pair are on a separate line."

Comment: Updated answer to new input format. Hope it works for you. :)

Comment: how can i resolve `Unterminated string` error? i have `about` json object on the file and i get this error: `FormatException: Unterminated string (at line 2, character 38)
{"about":"���� ���� �������� ���������� ���� ����������:}`

Comment: It looks like your JSON file is not in UTF-8. You need to use the correct decoder in Dart for your file if you want the content to be parsed correctly. If you don't care about this errors you can create the `Utf8Decoder` with `const Utf8Decoder(allowMalformed: true)` instead.

Comment: i get error again `.transform(const Utf8Decoder(allowMalformed: true))`

Comment: mail sent successfully

Comment: Ok, I have used my Dart code from this answer to run through your file and I don't get any charset problems. I think you need to publish your source code (or send it to my mail) so I can try run the same program that your have.

Comment: i replied to sent mail

Comment: Did not receive your second e-mail. I have tried to reply to you but got no response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218772/discussion-between-doldurma-and-julemand101).