# Dart append to file when i use transform in read text from file

Tags: dart

in this simple code i can show all fetched `ids` when finished reading file and get `id` from text file, but i want to append this fetched `id` inside `JsonObjectTransformer` class, not finished reading file

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final ids = await File('sample.json')
      .openRead()
      .transform(const Utf8Decoder())
      .transform<dynamic>(JsonObjectTransformer())
      .map((dynamic json) => json['id'] as String)
      .toList();

  print(ids); // [@123456, @123456]
}

class JsonObjectTransformer extends StreamTransformerBase<String, dynamic> {
  static final _openingBracketChar = '{'.codeUnitAt(0);
  static final _closingBracketChar = '}'.codeUnitAt(0);

  @override
  Stream<dynamic> bind(Stream<String> stream) async* {
    final sb = StringBuffer();
    var bracketsCount = 0;

    await for (final string in stream) {
      for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        final current = string.codeUnitAt(i);
        sb.writeCharCode(current);

        if (current == _openingBracketChar) {
          bracketsCount++;
        }

        if (current == _closingBracketChar && --bracketsCount == 0) {
          yield json.decode(sb.toString());
          sb.clear();
        }
      }
    }
    
    /*for example this line*/
    //new File('test.txt').writeAsStringSync(sb.toString(), mode: FileMode.APPEND);
  }
}
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Can you try describe what you want with an example showing the files before and after? I find it difficult to understand your problem based on your description and code example.

Comment: @julemand101 in this part of code `yield json.decode(sb.toString());` we can yield `sp` as `stream`, i want to write fetched `id` in this part of code to file when i fetch each id in `for` statement

Comment: It is this part "i want to write fetched id in this part of code to file when i fetch each id in for statement" I don't understand.

Comment: @julemand101 you answered my last post in this link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/62037974/1830228`

Comment: @julemand101 ok, how can i write fetched `id` inside `JsonObjectTransformer` class to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this but a simple way is to change the `JsonObjectTransformer` like this:

```
class JsonObjectTransformer extends StreamTransformerBase<String, dynamic> {
  static final _openingBracketChar = '{'.codeUnitAt(0);
  static final _closingBracketChar = '}'.codeUnitAt(0);

  @override
  Stream<dynamic> bind(Stream<String> stream) async* {
    final sb = StringBuffer();
    var bracketsCount = 0;
    final ioSink = File('test.txt').openWrite(mode: FileMode.append);

    await for (final string in stream) {
      for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        final current = string.codeUnitAt(i);
        sb.writeCharCode(current);

        if (current == _openingBracketChar) {
          bracketsCount++;
        }

        if (current == _closingBracketChar && --bracketsCount == 0) {
          final dynamic jsonObject = json.decode(sb.toString());

          ioSink.writeln(jsonObject['id'] as String);
          yield jsonObject;
          sb.clear();
        }
      }
    }
    
    await ioSink.flush();
    await ioSink.close();
  }
}
```

A more clean solution (since we want some separate of concern) would be to make use of the `Stream` in your main to write the ID's as each object are parsed. An example how to do that would be:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final file = File('test.txt').openWrite(mode: FileMode.append);
  final ids = <String>[];

  await File('sample.json')
      .openRead()
      .transform(const Utf8Decoder())
      .transform<dynamic>(JsonObjectTransformer())
      .map((dynamic json) => json['id'] as String)
      .forEach((id) {
    file.writeln(id);
    ids.add(id);
  });

  await file.flush();
  await file.close();

  print(ids); // [@123456, @123456]
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer with two examples of how you can achieve what you want. Please tell me if you want something else.

Comment: i think that work fine, how can i prevent inserting `null` into file?

Comment: You can add a `.where((event) => event != null)` in the second example before the `forEach`.